# Getting nested directory artifact without getting nested parent directories in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to get a nested directory's contents as a zipped artifact in my GitLab CI.

In this case, I want all files and directories within the `myapp` directory.

```yaml
artifacts:
  paths:
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/application/windows/AppPackages/myapp/
```

The problem is that the outputted folder (screenshot below) includes the entire directory chain as well. I only want the contents of the `myapp` folder (circled).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since version 13.1, GitLab has the ability to exclude files from artifacts:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexclude
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#exclude-files-from-job-artifacts

I've not used this feature myself so I can't provide an example, but the documentation links here should get you there.